# Finding Points of Inflection for a Specific Choose Function

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, gamma-distribution, combinatorics

If anyone could solve this puzzle, I would be incredibly thankful!

Given a bell-shaped distribution of ways to choose *r* from constant number *n*, how do we find the two points of inflection?

For example, given $n=500$, the graph would be that of the choose function:

$$f(r) = \binom{500}r, $$or $$f(r) = \frac{500! }{(500-r)! (r)!}$$

Trying to put everything in terms of the gamma function integral and taking the double derivative yields too many terms to keep track of, and it is quite hard to solve. Is there an easier way to find the two points of inflection?

Comment: Your description implies $r$ is an integer between $0$ and $500$.  Are you seeking an *integral* value for a discrete analog of an inflection point?  If not, then could you explain how this question might be connected to any issue of statistics or machine learning?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! No; the inflection point is likely a not a discrete integer -- if we assume the curve is connected by smooth lines to form a gaussian distribution, the inflection point must be some decimal. 

Anyways, I'm trying to use it to discover a special relationship of the choose function.

Comment: No matter how you join the integral points, you will not obtain a truly Gaussian distribution.  Perhaps you would be better off asking directly about this "special relationship" you seek, for otherwise you could wind up with correct but irrelevant answers.